# Java - How to get number of bytes in a DataInputStreaam?

Tags: java, networking, server, cycle, multiplayer

I am currently writing the server side of a multiplayer game I am working on. I need to know how much data is being received on the server socket, so I can cycle through each byte. For example, If I call `writeUTF()` twice, how will I cycle through each without getting an exception?

My first attempt was to simply try catch an `EOFException`. But you can't seem to catch those. So, how do I get the amount of data being received in a `DataInputStream`? If you need a code sample, please let me know and I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. The simplest solution is to have a separate thread per client.

Comment: @immibis Ok, thanks for the info! Ill just have to find another way to send it :)

Comment: There isn't really such a thing as the number of bytes in a stream. Consider a peer that just keeps sending data forever. And don't confuse the result of `available()` with it: there is a warning in the Javadoc saying specifically not to do that. And you most certainly *can* catch `EOFException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calls to read data from a socket will block until data is received. There is no way to find out how much data is in a stream. You have several ways to solve that and these are some suggestions:

- In your communication protocol,  include a length field or some command code that indicates the length.
- Use asynchronous read and write or use a thread dedicated to deal with communication.
- Before jumping on your keyboard and code, think about your app architecture, its components, their function and how they relate to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I found out another way to get it though, I found out about the available() method, and used it. I cycled through it that way, and put all the data in a ArrayList, then I cycled through the data using a for loop.

Comment: @SuperstarGamer-Trent JVMs are allowed to make available() always return 0. Some people would say available() is a design mistake that probably wouldn't exist if streams were invented today.

Comment: @immibis Yeah I know, normally, I wouldnt use it. But because the only data that is ever sent through the sockets is UTF, I will use it. Otherwise, I wouldnt. If you are wondering why I am sending only strings, it is because I have a library I made where I can make something similar to a ByteBuffer except into a String and then back. And yes, I can put longs, shorts, etc. Into it. If you want, I can send you a link to the jar so you can try it!

Comment: Using the available method, you will have to continuously poll the socket instead of being event driven. it should work though.

Comment: @SuperstarGamer-Trent I don't see how the fact that you only send strings has anything to do with the fact that you're polling with available().

Comment: @immibis There is no other type of data other than UTF (Strings) being sent, so it is safe to use available() with readUTF() to get all of the data, otherwise, I woudn't use it.

Comment: @SuperstarGamer-Trent why is it safe? It's not that it might return too little - it's that it *might always return 0*.

Comment: @immibis Hm, I didnt know that. Ill put a check in the program to handle that if that happens. Like I said, Normally, it isnt safe. But because I am handling only one type of data, I can use that to determine the amount of data sent. Otherwise, if I was sending things like Strings, Shorts, Longs, etc. I would not use it.

Comment: @SuperstarGamer-Trent what will you be using available() for, if you're fine with it always returning 0?

Comment: @immibis I am not. So far in my testing, It has not returned 0. I said I was going to add a handler for that if it happens, do you know a how to trigger this so I can go on and create a good way to handle it in the server?

Comment: @SuperstarGamer-Trent If it works on your Java version, fine... but it might not work on everyone's.

Comment: @immibis Ok, thanks for the warning! My Java Version is Java 8 and This is meant for private use, so that shouldn't be a problem. Also, do you know how the "0" Thing you were mentioning? I would love to know so I could add a handler :)

Comment: @SuperstarGamer-Trent Any solution that works if available() always returns 0, will not use available() at all, by the way.

Comment: @immibis Ok. Thanks for the info! I think I know a good way to send all of the data, since my data is in string format, send it all in one string, then put a "-" in the middle of the two? I don't know, Ill have to find a way to do so. But something similar, but for now, I will just use available(). Thank you for letting me know the available() is unreliable so I don't make a error in my coding causing my servers to malfunction :D

Comment: @SuperstarGamer-Trent I think I should clarify myself from before - available() isn't *guaranteed* to be reliable, but that doesn't mean that it's not *actually* reliable - it could be reliable on some or most or all systems anyway. But it's not guaranteed, so for 100% reliable code (that works on *any* Java system, including ones that haven't been created yet) , you can't assume it works.

Comment: @immibis Ah, Ok. But I will figure out another way that is 100% reliable! Thank you so much for the info! Have a great day! -Trent

Comment: @immibis UPDATE, I figured out I could try and catch EOFException, which is triggered when reading to much of any data type. Would adding data until that occurs (The UTF) and then break the loop and ignore it be safe? Since I know when its going to happen, and why it is?

Comment: @SuperstarGamer-Trent you will only get an EOFException if the stream is closed - but if you're closing the stream anyway, then yes. (The EOFException is guaranteed)

Comment: @immibis Ok, I'll use that instead. This way, I don't have a chance of getting 0. And, I don't have to worry about trying to get things that aren't strings (For example, I send a string and short, but the server tries to read two strings)